# Условия в хоткеях ATOM

Tags: atom

Возможно ли установить условие для хоткея в ATOM. Например:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-r': 'love-ide:run-love'
```

Ctrl+R будет пытаться выполниться и в файлах с расширением .lua и в .html и в .php. А мне хочется сделать условие, например Ctrl+R выполнять только в файлах с расширением .lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец нашел! Был раньше плагин [atom-keymap-plus](https://github.com/tcarlsen/atom-keymap-plus) который это делал, потом перенесли данный функционал в Native и реализуется вот так:

```
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='source js']":
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='source css']":
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='source json']":
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='text html basic']":
```